# 3-manifolds with one spherical boundary component

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, low-dimensional-topology

My question is the following:

> Can all compact, connected and orientable 3-dimensional topological manifolds $\mathcal{M}$ with connected boundary $\partial\mathcal{M}\cong S^{2}$ be obtained by removing a closed ball inside some arbitrary closed, connected and orientable 3-manifold $\mathcal{N}$?

Furthermore, I know that there is also the notion of manifolds with "incompressible" boundary. However, I am far from beeing an expert on this, so I am not sure if this can happen in this case...

Comment: The quantifiers in your question are not at all clear. Are you asking whether for all $\mathcal M$ there exists $\mathcal N$ such that ...? Or whether there exists $\mathcal N$ such that for all $\mathcal M$ ...? Or something else?

Comment: Well, given a compact orientable 3-manifold with $S^2$ boundary, you can always glue a copy of $B^3$ to that boundary to obtain a closed orientable 3-manifold... Does that answer the question?